tools not support python3.12 to decompile python pyc file to py

I have a Python project created using python3.12.


It was converted to exe. I lost my project codes. I have no solution


to get my codes other than returning the exe file to Python again.


The extracted file is pyc. I used several tools such as:


Uncompile6 And  decompile3


But it does not support python 3.12


see:  "I understand you need a volunteer to salvage the Python decompiler effort."   ( https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3/issues/45#issuecomment-1777564470 )
